# Is true that if $A,B$ have the same number of countable subsets, then $A=_{c} B$?

Tags: set-theory

Is it true the following statement?

"Let $A,B$ whose have the same number of countable subsets.Then $A=_{c} B$."

I think it's false and i try to find $A,B$ whose satisfy the following property but they haven't the same cardinal number.If $A,B$ are countable the following property says $\mathcal{P}(A)=_{c}\mathcal{P}(B)$.

Could this help to find the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume $A =_c B$ means that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality? If that is the case, note that both $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have $2^{\aleph_0}$-many countable subsets.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Interestingly enough, this fact depends on the axiom of choice!